# How do you log in basketball stats a desperate shot attempt at shot clock buzzer?

Tags: basketball, statistics

In basketball, the 24 second shot clock buzzer is about to sound, team in possession of the ball throws it up towards the basket.

According to some sources this not registered as a shot attempt. Now, what do we with rebounds? If there is no shot attempt there is no rebound, correct?

A. The ball touches the rim. So technically both teams can contest the rebound. Still no rebound situation, right? So if the offensive team retrieves the ball there is nothing logged yet if they lose the ball then it is a team turnover and just a change of possession or something like that, no?

B. The ball does not touch the rim. Offensive team turnover and that's it, correct?